# Android - Click to expand

Tags: android, onclick, expand

In my layout, I want to add a TextView which on click expands and shows some more text. I can't display a dialog as I don't know to change the font of it's message. I think click to expand will be better. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implement this custom TextView on Github which I think implements an expandable text view as you require? > https://github.com/Manabu-GT/ExpandableTextView

Comment: I m using eclipse, will just importing that bundle do? Also do i require any license for using it?

Comment: how do i use it in eclipse?

Comment: Just download the repo on github (via git or download the zip file) and then import the 'lib' folder into Eclipse as a library project.  The licence for this code is Apache 2.0 so is free to use in personal and commercial projects as far as I know (if your happy with the answer then give me a +1 if you can :-) Thanks!).